# Node.js Module, function isn't exporting properly

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to create utility functions, usually use python and getting used to node, this function won't export for some reason - says "SaveJson is not a function".

```
exports.mySaveJson = function(obj) {
    var blob,file,fileSets,obj;

      /**
     * Creates a file in the local drive
     */
    var date = new Date();
    var fs = require('fs');


     var n = date.toString();
     var name = n.concat("_scraped_data.json"); 
     //  console.log(name)


     fileSets = {
       name: name,
       mimeType: 'application/json'
     };



     blob = JSON.stringify(obj);
     file = fs.writeFile(fileSets, blob, callback);
return file;


   };
```

into

```
const SaveJson = require("./utilities.js")
....
SaveJson(ans)
```

Love some help just understanding what is wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling:

```
const SaveJson = require("./utilities.js")
SaveJson(ans)
```

You need to call the actuall named function that you exported like:

```
const Util = require("./utilities.js")
Util.mySaveJson(ans);
```

Also, if you export multiple functions in `utilities.js` like:

```
exports.mySaveJson = function(obj) {
   ...
}
exports.getJson = function() {
   ...
}
```

Then you can easily call this utility functions in any js file like:

```
const Util = require("./utilities.js")
...
Util.mySaveJson(ans);
const data = Util.getJson();
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should say `SaveJson.mySaveJson(ans);`

You are getting the module not the function. These are different things:

```
const {mySaveJson} = require('./utitities.js');
```

and

```
const SaveJson = require('./utitities.js');
```

`The First One` extracts the exact function out of the module and sets it to the variable

`The Second One` sets the whole module into the variable.